# Finding the greatest amount of consecutive values in an array (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to solve a problem that I can't seem to wrap my head around and was hoping I could get a little bit of insight from someone more experienced than I am. Basically, I have an array that has anywhere from 10 to 500 values. These values are all either true or false, but they are in a random order. I need to know the greatest amount of times that false appears in a row. For example:

```
[false, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, false]
```

Should return 3, since it appears 3 times in a row at the most. This seems like a potentially common problem to solve but I couldn't find a solution through searching. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? If you're stuck - how would you solve it by hand? That's usually a good starting point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use one value to keep count of consecutive false values and if that value is larger then current max set max value to that value. If value is `true` you reset counter to `0`.

```js
var arr = [false, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, false]
var c = 0, max = 0;

arr.forEach(function(e) {
  e == false ? c++ : c = 0;
  if (c > max) max = c;
})

console.log(max)
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, seems like the answer was right under my nose the whole time. Very much appreciated!

Comment: Glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the `forEach` function, and then have an internal counter, for example:

```js
console.log( countConsecutive([false, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, false]) );

function countConsecutive( arr )
{
   var c = 0;
  
   arr.forEach(function(e) {  
     (e == false) ? c++ : c = 0;
  });
  
  return c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function to count number of consecutive `false` in array:

```
function countNumFalse(arr){
    var max = 0;
    var condFalse = false;
    var numFalse = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        condFalse = condFalse || arr[i];
        if(condFalse === true){
           condFalse = false;
           numFalse = 0;
        }
        else{
             numFalse++;
          if(numFalse > max){
             max = numFalse;
          }
        }
    }
    return max;
}

var arr1 = [false, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, false];

countNumFalse(arr1);
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourArray=[false,true,true,false,false,false,true];
arrayLength = yourArray.length;
var maxCount=0;
var currentCount=0;
var lastElement;

for(var i = 0;i<arrayLength;i++){
    if(lastElement === yourArray[i]){
        currentCount++;
    }
    else{
        if(currentCount>maxCount){
            maxCount=currentCount;
        }
        currentCount=1;
    }
    lastElement=yourArray[i];
}
console.log(maxCount);
```

This should suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

Here's a funky, but one-lined solution:

```
var arr = [false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false, false, true];

var consec = arr.join('').split('true').reduce((i, x) => Math.max((x.match(/false/g) || []).length, i), 0);
```

Steps explained:

1. Convert the array to a string
2. Split the new string on the values we
   *don't* want to create an array of each of the consecutive items in string form.
3. Then reduce that array and within the reduce
   function, count the number of matches via a regex match - and find
   the maximum number of those matches.

Point of note - this really only works with binary lists `[true, false]`, `[1,0]`, etc.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/634rump0/2/).